# can we use supercapacitor in filter circuits?

Tags: power-supply, filter, supercapacitor

Supercapacitors combine the advantages of a battery and a capacitor, i.e., faster charging, slower discharging.

We also know that however good a filter circuit is, there remains a ripple when converting an a.c voltage to d.c.

So my question is, can we use supercapacitor instead of capacitors, to minimize, or even diminish the ripple factor, and obtain a superior DC voltage?

Comment: The advantage of batteries is having a higher energy density, I don't see where supercars have any of this

Comment: You can charge a 50C LiPo battery of equivalent Farad capacity much faster than a SuperCap. due to thermal conductance.

Comment: If you want to get a higher voltage, it makes more sense to simply use a transformer with higher output voltage.

Answer (score 5):

Supercaps are not well suited to reducing ripple of something like a dumb diode rectifier power supply because they have large ESR (equivalent series resistance) compared to other types of caps.  A plain old electrolytic is better, then followed by active circuitry to flatten out the result.

In some cases, large power supply caps aren't used at all anymore.  Power supplies that do PFC (power factor correction), for example, deliberately don't have any capacitance immediately after the full wave bridge.  The raw rectified AC goes into a switching power supply directly, which adjusts its current draw to stay proportional to the input voltage.  There is still a cap after the switcher, but supercaps are even less suited for that role since the ripple frequency is much higher than the 50 or 60 Hz line frequency.  At 100 kHz or more, ESR and ripple current capability are important, and large amount of capacitance less important.

Answer (score 4):

The only advantage of SuperCaps or UltraCaps or "double-electric layer capacitors" is that they can endure millions of charge discharge cycles unlike rechargeable batteries with much lower limits.

Batteries are superior in all other ways including ; energy storage density, initial cost, size per watt hour or Ah , Joules/gram. Etc
[image]
Perhaps Ultracaps can offer ultra low ESR for applications like 1kW trunk audio Amps that need >100 Amp pulses with heavy power cables.  However better performance with a 700 CCA battery in the trunk would perform better than a 10F Ultracap, but for safety reasons with rear collisions, it is not advisable.

Ultracaps can also make excellent temporary storage power for portable Irons with charge bases between ironing every 10 seconds or more and last for many many years. (e.g. Panasonic makes these)

There are many more applications but they are **not useful** for powering LEDs or amplifiers or any other nonlinear voltage dependent source. Why? because you need a DC-DC PSU that can consume the entire voltage range and the supercaps cannot handle the same charge current per unit storage (Ah) as a battery. (Comparing only same physcial sizes)

Why? because to consume all the energy \$ E = \frac{1}{2} CV^2 \$ you have to drain all the charge from 100% to 0% , whereas a battery only has to change 10-20% V over it's State of Charge Voltage range.  e.g. 12.5 to 11.5 ( car)  or 3.9 to 3.5 (LiPo) Batteries also enable overvoltage to speed up charging ( e.g. 4.2 (LiPo) , 14.2V(car) whereas Ultracaps can blow up if you exceed their voltage rating!  ( with safety vents for gradual overvoltage)

How many Farads do you think there are in a 16850 little LiPo cell?

- a) none
- b) 1uF
- c) 1000 uF
- d) 1 Farad
- e) 1000 Farads
- f) more

Proof: Biggest Ultracap vs Car battery

- [Largest Ultracap at D-K](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/electric-double-layer-capacitors-edlc-supercapacitors/131084?k=&pkeyword=&pv13=1538&FV=fff40002%2Cfff8000c&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=100)

  - Nichicon 6000Farads JJD0E608MSEH  Description (EDLC) Supercapacitor 2.5V Radial, Can - Screw Terminals 2.2m Ohm Cost $326 usd
  - E=1/2CV^2= 1/2 (6000) * 2.5^2= 18.75 kJ 
    .
- 12V car battery 850CCA 65Ah rating $75usd Room temp ~950A

  - CCA=5Vdrop@950A = 5.3 mOhm
  - E= 12Vx65Ah*3600s = ~2800 kJ or **150 times more energy than the biggest ultracap** at < 1/3 of the price.

Answer (score 1):

A supercapacitor is just a big capacitor. If this would help then adding more normal capacitors would also reduce output ripple.

This gives us a nice easy way to test the idea. Take a power supply and stick a bigger capacitor on the output. Does it get better?

The answer is that yes, up to a certain point it helps. But beyond that point other effects e.g. the inductance of the pins and the capacitors ESR start to have an impact and reduce the smoothing effect.

Answer (score 1):

> can we use supercapacitor instead of capacitors, to minimize, or even
>   diminish the ripple factor, and obtain a superior DC voltage?

I think you are missing the point about filters. There are NO filters that seek to totally minimize ripple. Take, for instance, the ubiquitous low pass filter - you want to be able to get a voltage out of it that is somewhat representative of the incoming DC level but, you don't want to wait minutes or hours for this to happen.

With the biggest capacitor in the world fed from a pretty big resistor your "average voltage measuring" circuit would take absolutely ages to respond to a step change. Functionally this would be [pants](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pants).

So, instead you decide how quickly you want it to respond and how little ripple you want. From this you decide a cut-off frequency (maybe 1 Hz) and weigh up how much ripple will be introduced (say from a power frequency such as 50 or 60 Hz). These are all easily calculated and visualized once you know how.

From this you choose the number of 1st order stages (that's one resistor and one capacitor) you might need to cascade to obtain what you desire. You might also decide to inter-twine two 1st order stages and make what is known as a peaking second order low pass stage (it has potentially better responsiveness and lower output ripple that two independant 1st order stages).

That's how EEs design filters; there is a steady state factor and a transient factor and both are usually equally important.

Answer (score 1):

An RC low pass filter as used in a power supply will have a ripple that is inversely proportional to the capacitance, **ideally**. However double layer caps tend to have rather high ESR so the total impedance is higher (they add in quadrature as Resr + 1/jwC). There is a practical limit as to what can be achieved in a single filer section.

So having a high capacitance can help, up to a point, but reducing ripple and noise is often better attacked by reducing the ripple to a reasonable amount then adding more passive (RC or LC) filter sections, adding an active regulator or a capacitance multiplier stage.